# Selecting the row subgroup with the max value of a variable

Tags: r

so I have a data frame:

```
ID:    YearMon:   Var: Count:
1      012007      H            1
1      012007      D            2
1      022007                   NA
1      032007      H            1
2      012007      H            1
2      022007                   Na
2      022007      D            1
2      032007                   NA
```

How would i go about getting just the max value for each unique ID for a certain YearMon? Ideally it would return:

```
1      012007      D            2
1      022007                   NA
1      032007      H            1
2      012007      H            1
2      022007      D            1
2      032007                   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plyr` this should be easily achieved. This will filter by ID and YearMon and return the max value along with the ID and YearMon in a data frame.

```
library(plyr)

ddply( dat1 , .(ID,YearMon)  ,function(x) {
Count = max( x$Count )
data.frame( Count=Count , Var=x[x$Count == Count,"Var"] )
})
```

In order to return all Columns:

```
df[ is.na( df$Count ) , "Count" ] <- -9999

df2 <- ddply(df, .(ID,YearMon) , function(x){

Count = max( x$Count )
index = which( x$Count == max( x$Count ))
y <- x[ index ,]                                
data.frame( y )

})

df2[ df2$Count == -9999, "Count" ] <- NA
```

This will return your indexing values back to NA as well.

Comment: When I run this replacing dat1 with my data set, I am getting the error object 'Count' not found  although the variable name in my dataTable is Count. Is there something else I should be replacing as well?

Comment: Yea sorry I fixed that in my code but not my answer, should function now.

Comment: Awesome worked perfectly. How would I go about returning an entire row from my old dataframe instead of creating a new one with only the 3 variables?

Comment: I'm seeing below that you are interested in the NA's, I would suggest changing the NA's to a value in order to keep them. I will adjust above to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, if you have a data table called `dt`, you can first calculate the max of Count by group, and then just keep the rows where Count is equal to the max for that group:

```
newdt <- dt[, max.count := max(Count), by=.(ID, YearMon)][Count==max.count,.(ID, YearMon, Var, Count)]
```

Comment: Hi, this worked really well, but is there a way to keep the rows with NA as well?

Comment: @swagbag By definition when you group by ID and Year Month and take the max NA's will be removed. If you want to keep them you need to create a third NA variable to group by.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  group_by(ID, YearMon) %>%
  slice(Count %>% which.max)
```

Comment: I found this very helpful, thank you. Can you please explain your code?
 Specifically the last line involving `slice`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets not forget about aggregate!

```
  #####Clean up data. You need to change your grouping variables to factors and data needs to be numeric####

dat1$Var.[dat1$Var.==1]=""
dat1$Count.<-as.numeric(dat1$Count.)
dat1$ID.<-as.factor(dat1$ID.)
dat1$YearMon.<-as.factor(dat1$YearMon.)
dat1<-dat1[,-3] ###Lets get rid of the Var column as you're not using it.


aggregate(. ~ ID.+YearMon.,data = dat1,FUN=max ) #### Use aggregate. Simple and short code
  ID. YearMon. Count.
1   1    12007      2
2   2    12007      1
3   2    22007      1
4   1    32007      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `data.table` option using `if/else`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', 'YearMon', `if` `all` of the 'Count' values are 'NA' we return the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) or `else` we get the index of maximum value of 'Count' and subset the data.table (`.SD[which.max(Count)]`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(all(is.na(Count))) .SD else .SD[which.max(Count)],.(ID, YearMon)]
 #   ID YearMon Var Count
 #1:  1   12007   D     2
 #2:  1   22007        NA
 #3:  1   32007   H     1
 #4:  2   12007   H     1
 #5:  2   22007   D     1
 #6:  2   32007        NA
```

Or another option would be to concatenate the index from `which.max` and the rows which have all 'NA' for 'Count' grouped by the variables, get the row index (`.I`) and use that to subset the 'data.table'.

```
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[c(which.max(Count), all(is.na(Count)))], .(ID, YearMon)]$V1]
#   ID YearMon Var Count
#1:  1   12007   D     2
#2:  1   22007        NA
#3:  1   32007   H     1
#4:  2   12007   H     1
#5:  2   22007   D     1
#6:  2   32007        NA
```

Or we `replace` the NA by a very small number, use `which.max` and subset

```
setDT(df1)[, .SD[which.max(replace(Count, is.na(Count),-Inf ))], .(ID, YearMon)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
 YearMon = c(12007L, 
12007L, 22007L, 32007L, 12007L, 22007L, 22007L, 32007L), Var = c("H", 
"D", "", "H", "H", "", "D", ""), Count = c(1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 
NA, 1L, NA)), .Names = c("ID", "YearMon", "Var", "Count"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```